# Best way to conditionally render HTML content if user is an admin in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an **ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC** application and I want to conditionally render HTML based on the currently logged-in user's role. My current approach is to use a **ViewComponent** that will either render the links or not render the links based on the user's defined role. For example, if the user is authorized (based on his/her role) for the controller actions that those links perform, the ViewComponent will render the links. If the user is not authorized, the ViewComponent will will hide the links altogether. Does anyone have a better approach? (The action methods in the controllers are appropriated decorated with the Authorize annotation; e.g., **[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]**.)